# WCF without IIS or installation

Tags: .net, wcf, ipc

Essentially I have a portable suite of windows 7 apps that are managed by a single backbone application.  This backbone application handles monitoring the other apps for status and heartbeat.  I want to use WCF and named pipes to handle communication between these processes, but ideally I would like it to be portable.  I can guarantee that .net 4.5 is installed.  The issue is that I don't want to install a WAS service and I can't use IIS.  Is there a way to do this, such as a WAS service that is loaded at runtime?  I know that I can roll my own named pipe for multicasting, but would much rather leverage the wrappers that WCF offers if possible.

Comment: you mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx (self hosting)?

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need.  Thanks!